# WP7: Farseer for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, farseer

Im struggling to setup [Farseer](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/64108) for WP7 Silverlight. Which version is the correct one for Silverlight on WP7? The "Farseer Physics Engine 3.2 WP7"-version only seem to work with XNA-projects and all Silverlight-builds seem to be targeting Silverlight 4... ?

Comment: If you can get it working, I would be interested in seeing what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Physics Helper](http://physicshelper.codeplex.com/) library on codeplex, really easy to get up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

go here: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/64108

and download:

Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 Silverlight
Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 SimpleSamples Silverlight

now I've tested it in xna and works well, It's just not so simple at beginning, by the way is the most used on wp7.

To me the best method is to use blend and behavior video Spruce have right!

check it here http://physicshelper.codeplex.com/